# How to use Material-UI in asp.net mvc project

Tags: material-ui

Is there a way of using Material-UI without having to go through installing all of the dependencies using NodeJS. I would love to use this in an ASP.NET Project but dont know where to begin as per installing dependencies and all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Technically using Material UI without any frontend infrastructure is possible, but it's not recommended.

If you really don't want to use npm and other JS build/bundling tools you can use the UMD distribution of Material UI.

The [Getting started (#CDN)](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#cdn) page should help.

In short, you can add React, Babel, and Material UI using plain old `script` tags in your HTML:

```html
<head>
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <!-- Fonts to support Material Design -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
  />
  <!-- Icons to support Material Design -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
</head>
```

then write your JS in a `<script type="text/babel">` tag:

```html
<script type="text/babel">
  const {
    Button,
    ThemeProvider,
    createTheme
  } = MaterialUI;

  const theme = createTheme();

  function App() {
    return (
      <Button>Hello, world</Button>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>,
    document.querySelector('#root'),
  );
</script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

See https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn for a working example.

---

This solution is great for prototyping, but not suitable for production apps. The primary reason for this is low performance. Browsers must download the whole library (including the parts you don't use in your application) and Babel must compile your React app on the fly.

A much better approach is to have an ASP.NET API application and a separate frontend application using React and Material UI that is built using JS tools.

Answer (score -2):

it's very easy.. Follow the below steps.

1. Commit all the existing changes to your source control or backup existing code.
2. delete or comment twitter bootstrap bundles in bundle config.
3. using NPN .. install material design lite package.
4. add all the .css and .js references to bundles.
5. add new bundles you added to the layout page.
6. Remember to change all the class that uses twitter bootstrap to material design lite.

useful sources:

- [Learning Material Design](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/materialdesignlite/)
- [MDL Website](https://getmdl.io/)

Comment: this doesn't help!

Comment: 3. using NPN .. install material design lite package.
4. add all the .css and .js references to bundles. 
But NPM install files to node_modules. This folder is hidden in project and you can't add this to BundleConfig((((.

Comment: https://getmdl.io/started/index.html  Add the two link elements and the script element as this page states.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i think OP meant material-ui.com which are react components design for nodejs and installable through npm.