# Use Google Material UI in ASP Net CORE MVC project

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-core, material-design

How do I add Google Material Icons into MVC Net Core Project?
I followed these directions in my project folder by adding all the zip files. Just curious what is next step?

https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/

```
npm install material-design-icons
```

This link below is outdated.

[How to use Material-UI in asp.net mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934960/how-to-use-material-ui-in-asp-net-mvc-project)

Currently Using MVC Core Net Core 2.2.Company does not want to apply CDN URL route.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesign.Icons/

Comment: Can you add some examples of using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used `npm` to install , it will created a folder called `node_modules` (possibly hidden in Solution Explorer, click `Show All Files` button to check it ).

You have to write some script (gulp, grunt, etc) to move the files from `node_modules`directory to `wwwroot/lib` file :

[How to use npm with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935524/how-to-use-npm-with-asp-net-core)

[How to install font-awesome in Visual Studio 2017 using ASP.NET Core v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552235/how-to-install-font-awesome-in-visual-studio-2017-using-asp-net-core-v2)

If using gulp , you can try with :

```
gulp.task('copy', ["clean"], function () {
    return gulp.src(['./node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/*'], {
        base: 'node_modules'
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib'));
});
```

And can reference the css file in `_Layout.cshtml` .

Note :Currently use **Library Manager(LibMan)** to restore `material-design-icons` always fail in my testing .

Answer (score 1):

I used this 3 simple steps and worked for me

1. go to [this cdn](https://www.cdnpkg.com/MaterialDesign-Webfont/4.9.95) and download all google font files in it
2. copy all css files that you download it in `css` folder
3. create a folder with `fonts` name in `wwwroot` , and copy other files (font files)that you download it

its ready do use
just add css link to your project and enjoy